# Is this patent still valid and in force? 1

Tags: status, valid

uk patent application GB 2340070 A IS VALIAD AND INFORCE ?

Comment: I was not the down voter, but questions that are correctly punctuated and spelled are less likely to be down voted.

Answer (score 1):

Still valid, 20th year renewal paid on 26 July 2017. 
Please see https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-ipsum/Case/PublicationNumber/GB2340070.

Comment: This would be an even better answer if you mentioned the expiration date which, I believe, is rather soon.